# Apache DateUtils truncate day of month

Tags: java, calendar, apache-commons-dateutils

I would like to create a DateHelper class and for that I'm using DateUtils from Apache Commons Lang 2.6.
I'm having problems understanding the result returned when extract field from a date.  Here is my test class which extract the day of month after truncate the date :

```
    public class DateTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      Date date = createDate(2000, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

        Calendar calendar = createEmptyUTCCalendar();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2000);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0); // january
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 4);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 6);

        Date date = calendar.getTime();
    System.out.println("Input date\n" + date);

    // Truncate from day of month.
    Date dateTruncate = getDatePart(date);
    System.out.println("Truncate the date\n" + dateTruncate);

    System.out.println("\n*** Extract day of month ***");
    // Extract the field day of month from the truncated date.
    int fieldDayOfMonth = getField(dateTruncate, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println("Expected result is 2\nActual result is " + fieldDayOfMonth);

        assert fieldDayOfMonth == 2;
    }

     public static int getField(Date date, int calendarField) {
        Calendar calendar = createEmptyUTCCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int value = calendar.get(calendarField);
        if (calendarField == Calendar.MONTH) {
            value++;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static Date getDatePart(Date date) {
        return DateUtils.truncate(date, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }

    private static Calendar createEmptyUTCCalendar() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.clear();
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        return calendar;
    }
}
```

I expect the result of extracting the field Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH to be 2 but I got 1.

```
Input date
Sun Jan 02 04:04:05 CET 2000
Truncate the date
Sun Jan 02 00:00:00 CET 2000

*** Extract day of month ***
Expected result is 2
Actual result is 1
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to either use an external library (joda time) or Java 8? Can you please formulate your task in a few words and give some examples of expected input / output. Thanks

Comment: I can't use Joda Time or Java 8.

Comment: Looks like you change the timeZone. can you output the time after you create a new calendar?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2000 , Month.JANUARY , 2 )
         .getDayOfMonth()
```

> 2

## java.time

You can just use Java now, no need for Apache DateUtils. And truncation is the wrong way to think about it; just interrogate for the day-of-month property.

Specify your date using [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class. Note that java.time uses sane month numbering, 1-12 for January to December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2000 , 1 , 2 ) ;  // January 2, 2000.
```

Or use the `Month` enum.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2000 , Month.JANUARY , 2 ) ;  // January 2, 2000.
```

> 2000-01-02

Interrogate for day-of-month. You can call `getDayOfMonth` on a `LocalDate`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime`.

```
int dayOfMonth = ld.getDayOfMonth​() ;
```

> 2

If receiving a `Calendar` object, it is likely a `GregorianCalendar`. If so, you can easily convert to java.time classes.

```
if( myCalendar instanceOf GregorianCalendar ) {
    GregorianCalendar gc = ( GregorianCalendar ) myCalendar ;  // Cast.
    ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime() ;  // Convert from legacy class to modern class.
    int dayOfMonth = zdt.getDayOfMonth​() ;
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the thing is on the timezones. Your calendar is on UTC and your date on your local zone, if you avoid the line:

```
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

the thing should work.

When you pass calendar to Date, the date object gets default time zone CET in your case. Then you truncate and pass again to a UTC calendar, and due to the diffenrence between CET and UTC you day is the previous one.

Comment: I set the time zone to UTC because I want to test my time in UTC time.